# Showing there exists two numbers beloging to S whose sum is also in the set S

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, inclusion-exclusion

- Set of $16$ numbers are chosen from $[1,29]$ , show that there are always atleast $3$ numbers in that set so that sum of two of them results in the third number .

> My first method :.                           I thought of trying PHP , but i am really confused what hole type should be considered , i know it should be having property of what its being needed , so i thought of ${1,2,3}$ as a box where property os being satisfied $1+2=3$ , but still it will give us only about $11$ boxes we want $15$  , i dont know what to do now . Although i think these types of box will not work since i could chose later 1,3 only and not $2$ .

- My second method : i realize mahbe better would be do like taking all possible pairs of $a_i ,a_j$ both belonging to set $S$ and taking sum of the pairs each and then making that as a set of $\binom{16}{2}$ elements and then trying to get a counter example but finally showing that one element out of that would indeed be in the set S itself .

> By either method if possible i need a solution as such i dont get how to fully solve it from these ideas .

- Note : @GregMartin idea of largest element,i was able to prove it , but how do we prove it without observing that critical idea ?

Comment: Hint: show that the largest element of $S$ is the sum of two other elements of $S$.

Comment: Thanks im trying that

Comment: I am not able to prove it , can you show it @GregMartin

Comment: If $m$ is the largest element, consider the boxes $\{1,m-1\}$ and $\{2,m-2\}$ and....

Comment: I think i get it , we need to take cases of m being odd and even and showing in both cases upper bound of pigeonholes is stricltly less than n+1 right @GregMartin , or is there a way without taking cases of the parity of m ?

Comment: I proved it now @GregMartin , but without striking that largest element idea , how will do this problem ?

Comment: Greg Martin's idea strikes me as optimal.  Why do you wish to use another method?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yeah i understand that , i mean imagine we are first time given this problem , how would one would be get to know the critical idea of largest element fact . Just observing few cases or is it kinda intuitive ?